# Passing strings in Android void to public

Tags: java, android, string

I've got a try{} below to set a String confirmation to "payment confirmed." I want to setDescription() to the String confirmation. How do I pass this String from the void onActivityResult to the public class EndpointsTask?

```
 @Override
protected  void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                String confirmation = "payment confirmed";







            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
    }
    else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
    }
}


public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();





  try {




      ContactInfo note = new ContactInfo().setDescription(confirmation);
      String noteID = new Date().toString();
      note.setId(noteID);

      EditText streetName;
      streetName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.streetAddress);
      String streetInfo = streetName.getText().toString();
      note.setStreetAddress(streetInfo);

      EditText firstNameText;
      firstNameText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.firstName);
      String firstNameInfo = firstNameText.getText().toString();
      note.setNameFirst(firstNameInfo);

      EditText lastNameText;
      lastNameText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.lastName);
      String lastNameInfo = lastNameText.getText().toString();
      note.setNameLast(lastNameInfo);

      EditText emailText;
      emailText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.textemail);
      String emailInfo = emailText.getText().toString();
      note.setEmailAddress(emailInfo);

      EditText zipText;
      zipText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.zipCode);
      String zipInfo = zipText.getText().toString();
      note.setZipCode(zipInfo);

      EditText stateText;
      stateText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.state);
      String stateInfo = stateText.getText().toString();
      note.setState(stateInfo);

      EditText phoneText;
      phoneText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.phoneNumber);
      String phoneInfo = phoneText.getText().toString();
      note.setPhone(phoneInfo);





      ContactInfo result = endpoint.insertContactInfo(note).execute();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return (long) 0;
    }
}
```

EDITED CODE, Now why do I end up with two entries in my datastore view each time I hit the button.

```
   @Override
protected  void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));

                String confirmation = "payment confirmed";

                EndpointsTask task = new EndpointsTask(confirmation);
                task.execute(this);



                // TODO: send 'confirm' to your server for verification.
                // see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
                // for more details.

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
    }
    else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
    }
}


public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {

    String confirmation;
    public  EndpointsTask(String confirmation ) {
    this.confirmation = confirmation;
    }


    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Contactinfoendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Contactinfoendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Contactinfoendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();





  try {




      ContactInfo note = new ContactInfo().setDescription(confirmation);
      String noteID = new Date().toString();
      note.setId(noteID);

      EditText streetName;
      streetName = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.streetAddress);
      String streetInfo = streetName.getText().toString();
      note.setStreetAddress(streetInfo);

      EditText firstNameText;
      firstNameText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.firstName);
      String firstNameInfo = firstNameText.getText().toString();
      note.setNameFirst(firstNameInfo);

      EditText lastNameText;
      lastNameText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.lastName);
      String lastNameInfo = lastNameText.getText().toString();
      note.setNameLast(lastNameInfo);

      EditText emailText;
      emailText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.textemail);
      String emailInfo = emailText.getText().toString();
      note.setEmailAddress(emailInfo);

      EditText zipText;
      zipText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.zipCode);
      String zipInfo = zipText.getText().toString();
      note.setZipCode(zipInfo);

      EditText stateText;
      stateText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.state);
      String stateInfo = stateText.getText().toString();
      note.setState(stateInfo);

      EditText phoneText;
      phoneText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.phoneNumber);
      String phoneInfo = phoneText.getText().toString();
      note.setPhone(phoneInfo);





      ContactInfo result = endpoint.insertContactInfo(note).execute();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return (long) 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason why you are passing in an array of Context's into the doInBackground method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a constructor inside the EndpointsTask AsyncTask like so:

```
    public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {

    String confirmation;
    public RouteAsyncRunnerUI(String confirmation ) {
    this.confirmation = confirmation;
    }
}
```

So you can call the field confirmation within the EndpointsTask as confirmation and do what you like with it.

You call this constructor in your onActivityResult  class like so:

```
EndpointsTask task = new EndpointsTask(confirmation);
task.execute(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this does work to pass my string. I now seem to be registering two entries instead of one in my app engine console. I get one with the contactinfo and "payment confirmed" and I get one with "null" and the contactinfo. Any ideas?

Comment: @coconuts4eva, I'm guessing you only need the contactinfo and payment confirmed entry? Have you tried checking for null before passing/using the confirmation string?

Comment: I seemed to have had an execute in an onClick. I got rid of that and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a reason why you are passing in an array of Context's into the doInBackground method in the AsyncTask class. To pass in a string into the AsyncTask you can make the Class with parameterized types

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long>
```

and you may execute the task using

```
new EndpointsTask().execute("any", "amount", "of", "strings);
```

here is more documentation for [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)